# Declaring an empty Queryable?

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

How do I declare such a variable?

```
            var rData = from nc in ctx.NEWSLETTER_CLIENTS
                        join ni in ctx.NEWSLETTER_INDICES on nc.INDEX_NUM 
                                                          equals ni.INDEX_NUM
                        select new
                        {
                            ClientID = nc.CLIENT_ID,
                            Email = nc.CLIENT_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
                            Index = nc.INDEX_NUM,
                            MainClass = ni.MAIN_CLASS,
                            SubClass = ni.SUB_CLASS,
                            App1 = ni.VALUE_1,
                            App2 = ni.VALUE_2,
                            App3 = ni.VALUE_3,
                            App4 = ni.VALUE_4
                        };

        // Now I need to declare on a variable named fData under the function scope,
        // so I can later use it:

        var fData = ...; //What do I declare here?

        if(x)
            fData = fData.Concat(rData.Where(u => ...));
        if(y)
            fData = fData.Concat(rData.Where(u => ...));
        // etc
```

Comment: In this case you can use the [ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) to refactor it into one assignment, but the question as such remains interesting.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
IQueryable<type of p> fData = null;
```

If you want to use the query later (iow after the if):

```
var fData = Enumerable.Empty<type of p>().AsQueryable();
```

**Update:**

Now for using with anonymous types:

```
IQueryable<T> RestOfMethod<T>(IQueryable<T> rData)
{
  var fData = Enumerable.Empty<T>().AsQueryable(); // or = rData;

  if(x)
    fData = fData.Concat(rData.Where(u => ...));
  if(y)
    fData = fData.Concat(rData.Where(u => ...));

  return fData;
}

// original code location
var rData = some query;
var fData = RestOfMethod(rData);
```

**Update 2:**

As pointed out, the above does not actually work, as the predicate of `Where` does not know the type. You could refactor it some more to include the predicates in the parameters, example:

```
IQueryable<T> RestOfMethod<T>(IQueryable<T> rData, 
  Expression<Func<T,bool>> pred1,
  Expression<Func<T,bool>> pred2) 
{ ... }
```

**Update 3: (perhaps hacky)**

```
var fData = rData.Take(0); // should be cheap.
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it does help, see my edit for a clarification

Comment: @Shai: For anonymous types, not easily possible, but can by partially done by a little refactoring of the rest of the method.

Comment: @Shai: I have added an example of what I meant in my previous comment.

Comment: thanks - but that won't compile, as `RestOfMethod` doesn't know which members `u` contains...

Comment: @Shai: You are correct, and to refactor it more, will be messy :(

Comment: @Shai: Updated answer, but I think you will agree that it is messy and will be difficult to maintain.

Comment: thanks for your effort - see the answer I've just posted for this question, I`d be happy to hear some comments

Comment: @Shai: It is basically the same as my last update, both will work the same. The `Where` version might be easier on a database. +1

Comment: The `.Take(0)` seems to translate to SQL best with `Union`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the following solution might be bad (and even contain some unwanted overhead), *but*, it works:

```
var fData = from p in rData
            where 0 == 1
            select p;

if(x)
    fData = fData.Concat(rData.Where(u => ...));
if(y)
    fData = fData.Concat(rData.Where(u => ...));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can declare it as an **IQueryable** instead of a **var**.  The reason you can't declare fData as a **var** is because "var" needs to infer the type during declaration.  If you know the type ahead of time, you can declare it just fine.

```
IQueryable fData = null;
```

Even better, if you know the type of **p**, you can make it strongly typed with the generic form of IQueryable:

```
IQueryable<type-of-p> fdata = null;
```

Note that this assigns *null*!  If you try to use it, you'll get a null reference exception.  If you actually want an *empty* Queryable object, then use leppie's suggestion, and create an empty collection using the [Enumerable.Empty()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341042.aspx).[AsQueryable()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb507003) method chain.

Comment: I highly doubt the will work (or even compile) unless you cast `p` to object.

Comment: You don't need to cast p to object; everything is .NET is implicitly convertible to object.

Comment: It might work under .NET 4 due to covariance, but it will definitely fail on .NET 3.5.